# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.criaOpcao

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at ChildScope.$scope.criaOpcao (appCtrl.js:49)**

```
// chamada para quando o formulário é enviado
$scope.criaOpcao = function (opcao) {
  if (!$scope.projetoAtivo || !opcao) {
    return;
  }
  $scope.projetoAtivo.opcoes.push({
    title: opcao.title
  });
  // fecha o modal de opções
  $scope.opcaoModal.hide();

  // meio ineficiente, mas salva os projetos
  Projetos.save($scope.projetos);
};
```

Comment: `this.projetoAtivo.opcoes` is `undefined`

Comment: Please try to keep your questions and code comments in English. Just dumping a codeblock saying it's not working is an offtopic reason, be more specific. Read the [help/on-topic] before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

Either outside of the function but in your controller you should define this variable:

```
$scope.projetoAtivo = [];
```

OR in the start of the function this should be declared.

this is a simple use case where you're trying to call push method on a variable, but since the variable is not defined, its giving you undefined. This variable has to be first declared as an array to allow pushing elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the existence of `opcoes` and its type to be able to do `.push()`.

```
$scope.criaOpcao = function (opcao) {
  if (!$scope.projetoAtivo || !opcao) {
    return;
  }
  // prop 'opcoes' should exist and be an array
  if (
    $scope.projetoAtivo.hasOwnProperty('opcoes') 
    && angular.isArray($scope.projetoAtivo.opcoes)) {
    $scope.projetoAtivo.opcoes.push({
      title: opcao.title
    });
  }
  $scope.opcaoModal.hide();
  Projetos.save($scope.projetos);
};
```